# For all integer number $n$, if $n$ is prime, then $n^2+1$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was asked to state either the above statement is true or false.
If it is true then I must prove it.
If it is false then I must give a counter example.

However, I had tried to prove by contrapositive that n^2+1 is odd but how can I say for n is not a prime do I need to say that n=prime=odd again or what?

Comment: Start plugging in prime values for $n$ and see if you find a counterexample.

Comment: Even stronger statement: If $n$ is odd, then $n^2 + 1$ is even.

Comment: @HenryW. That's not a stronger statement: That's true and this is false :-P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false. 2 is prime but $2^2+1=5$ which is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: All primes are odd except for $2$.

Comment: can you elaborate more on that.

Comment: Yiyuan, I like your photo, where is it from?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling It is from CLANNAD's ending music.

Comment: @HenryW. tineye, or is your memory just that awesome ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling It is my memory.

Comment: @Neman the square of any odd number is odd, adding one to the result makes it even.

Comment: @Carry On Smiling Yes it is from Clannad, I liked the series a lot just a few years back when I was still in high school :)